# How to receive JSON data from silex controller in AJAX

Tags: php, json, ajax, silex

When I'm trying to receive JSON data from PHP file in AJAX everything works fine:

Test.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'root', '');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM table");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

echo json_encode($stmt);
?>
```

main.js

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log(myObj);
      document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = myObj[4].id + " " + myObj[4].tag1;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/project/app/models/Test.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

But when I'm trying to receive JSON from silex controller:

Ajax.php

```
namespace AI\models;
use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Api\ControllerProviderInterface;

class Ajax implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
  public function connect(Application $app){
    $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];
    $controllers->get('/', 'AI\models\Ajax::home');
    return $controllers;
  }

  public function home(Application $app){
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    $result  = $app['db']->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM table");
    $result->execute();
    $result = $result->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, \AI\models\Ajax::class);
    echo json_encode($result);

    return $app['twig']->render('ajax.twig');
  }

}
```

main.js

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log(myObj);
      document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = myObj[4].id;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/project/app/models/Ajax.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I get an error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (main.js:4)
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange @ main.js:4
```

I don't have any idea why there is a problem when I trying to receive JSON from a class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning json you should use the [JsonResponse Object](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response). Also you definitely don't want to render a template as you currently have, you just want json data, why render a template?

You could follow the docs previously linked but, fortunately [Silex has a helper method for returning json data](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/usage.html#json) and you don't even need to use the JsonResponse (directly):

```
<?php

public function home(Application $app){

  $result  = $app['db']->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM table");
  $result->execute();
  $result = $result->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, \AI\models\Ajax::class);

  return $app->json($result);
}
```

Comment: I want to return JSON inside controller because I need to get easily variables from URL to work with database queries, and then get data as a JSON. That is why I'm trying to render the template to get ajax script working with that page(including twig variables).

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem then. Can you edit your question and post the content of the ```ajax.twig file```?

Comment: Also I mean that in your AJAX call you don't want to render the template, you have to render the template to go to the page where your client code (JS) makes the AJAX call. Does this make sense?

Comment: I just wanted to to get a variable from route URL and use it to filter data from the database. Then, encode the data as a JSON and send it to AJAX. I sorted my problem by passing route variable from the controller as a session variable to PHP file where I used it in a query, encoded the data and got it from AJAX call. But thanks for the help anyway.